# display print() from python function using xampp

Tags: python, xampp

```
#! C:/Users/User/src/try_django/install/Scripts/python.exe

print ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("hello")

import cgi
from django.shortcuts import render
import request

def button(request):
    return render(request,'clust.php')


def output(request):
    data="hello world!"
    print(data)
    return render(request,'clust.php',{'data':data})
```

I am running my python in xampp. However, I cant display print data on my python page except "hello". how do I display print() from function on my html page?

Comment: `print()` writes to stdout, so unless the data to "display" is being fetched from stdout, it won't work.

Comment: so how can I make the code print "hello world!" ?

Comment: It already “prints” just fine, what matters is what you mean by _print_.

Comment: but "hello world" does not display on the browser except for "hello"

Comment: Have you done any research on how to do this? Surely the Django docs would cover this, no?

Comment: i already tried using Django and it works, but if i want to run it using xampp it does not... just wanted to try if i can do it on xampp

Comment: The code in your post appears to still be using Django though, am I missing something?

Comment: so i can't print data using function when i run python from xampp?

Comment: That's an incredibly vague/broad question, to the point that I don't think it's possible to answer conclusively.